# asp.net ListBox does not follow Enabled=false;

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is what i have tried but it is really not working  :

```
  listMediaType.Enabled = false;
```

over here the listMediaType is the listBox control and i am disabling it on a radio button change event when the values inside the listbox should not be selected by the user

```
  <asp:ListBox ID="listMediaType" runat="server" class="form-control" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="90px" Style="width: 300px"></asp:ListBox>
```

This is the cs file code :

```
protected void RequestMedium_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioInternal.Checked)
    {
        listMediaType.Enabled = false;

    }
    else if (radioExternal.Checked)
    {
        listMediaType.Enabled = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: change it to `listMediaType.Visible = false;` then test it, and see if the controller gone invisible on radio button changed. If that's true, then you're overriding the `listMediaType.Enabled = false;` somewhere else in your code.

Comment: tried visible false and it vanished but i checked my code i am not overriding the listMediaType.Enabled=false;

Comment: then it's overridden. Check the controller tag options in the ASPX, if there is `Enable="true"` delete it.

Comment: protected void RequestMedium_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioInternal.Checked)
        {
            listMediaType.Enabled = false;
            listMediaType.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (radioExternal.Checked)
        {
            listMediaType.Enabled = true;
            listMediaType.Visible = true;
        }
    }

Comment: can this be the reason ?

Comment: <asp:ListBox ID="listMediaType" runat="server" class="form-control" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="90px" Style="width: 300px"></asp:ListBox>

Comment: put those in your post

Comment: remove `else if (radioExternal.Checked)` to `if (radioExternal.Checked)` so separated conditions

Comment: nothing really happened even after that :( the options just move more to left and nothing else

Comment: This may help: [listbox enable=false not working](https://forums.asp.net/t/1962474.aspx?listbox+enable+false+not+working)

Comment: check your page events such as Page_Load() or any methods that executed on page_load.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer if anyone is looking for the solution :

```
 listMediaType.Attributes.Add("disabled","");
```